# Descriptions of Ethernet register/counter names?

Tags: ethernet, net, stats, drivers

Is there a manual/datasheet/some other resource that explains what do all these counters in `ethtool -S <interface>` mean? Some of them are self-explainatory, some aren't...

I'm taking them from e1000e source code (ethtool.c).

EDIT: just found and looking at [this document](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/8257x%20Developer%20Manual/Revision%201.8/), seems to be useful (p.271 - register descriptions, with links to explanation). Still, I'd welcome your insight.

```
rx_packets
tx_packets
rx_bytes
tx_bytes
rx_broadcast
tx_broadcast
rx_multicast
tx_multicast
rx_errors
tx_errors
rx_dropped_backlog
tx_dropped
multicast
collisions
rx_length_errors
rx_over_errors
rx_crc_errors
rx_frame_errors
rx_no_buffer_count
rx_missed_errors
tx_aborted_errors
tx_carrier_errors
tx_fifo_errors
tx_heartbeat_errors
tx_window_errors
tx_abort_late_coll
tx_deferred_ok
tx_single_coll_ok
tx_multi_coll_ok
tx_timeout_count
tx_restart_queue
rx_long_length_errors
rx_short_length_errors
rx_align_errors
tx_tcp_seg_good
tx_tcp_seg_failed
rx_flow_control_xon
rx_flow_control_xoff
tx_flow_control_xon
tx_flow_control_xoff
rx_long_byte_count
rx_csum_offload_good
rx_csum_offload_errors
rx_header_split
alloc_rx_buff_failed
tx_smbus
rx_smbus
dropped_smbus
rx_dma_failed
tx_dma_failed
```